# What are other ancient encyclopaedic texts like Pliny's “Naturalis Historia” that were available in medieval times?

Tags: middle-ages

The German historian of medieval thought, [Kurt Flasch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Flasch) claims in one of his books ("Das philosophische Denken im Mittelalter", my translation "philosophical thought in medieval times") the following:

> "If there was any interest in natural history, in botany or mineralogy, for example, people looked for explanations in Pliny's Naturalis Historia."[^1]

I'm wondering if you can think of other works that were available and actually used by medieval natural historians/philosophers. Was aristotle (or at least his natural history) not available to people in the (european) middle ages?

[^1]: ["Wenn überhaupt naturkundliche Tatsachen, z. B. der Botanik oder der Mineralogie, Interesse fanden, so suchte man die Erklärungen auf, die in Plinius’ Naturgeschichte gegeben waren."](https://books.google.de/books?id=321hDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT105&lpg=PT105&dq=Wenn+%C3%BCberhaupt+naturkundliche+Tatsachen,+z.+B.+der+Botanik+oder+der+Mineralogie,+Interesse+fanden,+so+suchte+man+die+Erkl%C3%A4rungen+auf,+die+in+Plinius%27+Naturgeschichte+gegeben+waren&source=bl&ots=EOdj14B873&sig=Rh77VfgT4vvrgpPSWSbR7wmYmZM&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Wenn%20%C3%BCberhaupt%20naturkundliche%20Tatsachen%2C%20z.%20B.%20der%20Botanik%20oder%20der%20Mineralogie%2C%20Interesse%20fanden%2C%20so%20suchte%20man%20die%20Erkl%C3%A4rungen%20auf%2C%20die%20in%20Plinius'%20Naturgeschichte%20gegeben%20waren&f=false)

P.S.: [I asked this question on the history SE as well.](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/35485/what-are-other-ancient-encyclopaedic-texts-like-plinys-naturalis-historia-wer)

Comment: Only logical works of Aristotle were available before the 13th century, see [Transmission of the Greek Classics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_of_the_Greek_Classics). [Strabo's Geographica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strabo#Geographica), which was similar to Pliny, was only translated in late 15th century.

Comment: The *Nine Books of Disciplines* by Marcus Terentius Varro (116BC-27BC) covers some of the same ground as Pliny and was a model for Pliny.  However the common ground (logic, arithmetic, geometry, ... ) does not include Natural Philosophy.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_encyclopedias#Ancient_times